# Api routes of next js working in local server but not in production

Tags: reactjs, next.js, comments

I'm trying to create a comment section for my web.

Every thing is working fine in local server

but in production, when I submit give me this error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYbTj.png)

[After reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CdsR.png)

Api in next js:

```
    export default async function CreateComment(req, res){
    
        const { name, comment, _id } = JSON.parse(req.body)
        await client.config({
            token: process.env.SANITY_AUTH_TOKEN
        }).create({
            _type: "comment",
            name,
            comment,
            blog:{
                _type: "reference",
                _ref: _id
            },
        })
        return res.status(200)
    }
```

Form from which I submit the data:

```
    const notify = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            location.reload()
        }, 3000);
    }
    function Form({ _id }) {
        const {
            register,
            handleSubmit,
            formState: { errors },
        } = useForm();
        const onSubmit = async (data) => {
                    fetch('/api/CreateComment', {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: JSON.stringify({ ...data, _id })
                })
                console.log(data)
            }
        return (<>
        <form id='my-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="name"></label>
                    <input {...register('name', { required: true })} type="text" id="name" minLength={3} />
                    {errors.name}
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="comment">Your comment</label>
                        <textarea {...register('comment', { required: true })} id="comment" rows="4" minLength={5}></textarea>
                        {errors.comment}
                    </div>
                    <div >
                        <button onClick={notify} type="submit">
                            Post comment
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </>
        );
```

I'm getting the _id from my slug.js

Edit:

In local server if i go to my api route i get this error

[image: error on api path]

But still it works in local server

Comment: the error you see when you go to the api route is normal since the endpoint expect some data to use it in `JSON.parse(req.body)` which you didn't provide. you can try to hit the endpoint with a program like [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/download)

Comment: one thing though I don't think you need to use JSON.parse(req.body) you can do `const { name, comment, _id } = req.body` because `req.body` is already parsed by Next.js middleware, read more on that [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/request-helpers)

Comment: Include your errors as text, not screenshots.